# Открыть порт на ПК linux

Tags: linux, сеть, port, пк

Как открыть порт в такой схеме: роутер, к нему присоединено 2 ПК? Нужно открыть порт 2222 на обоих компьютерах. В роутере я уже прописал оба правила. В iptables тоже, но подключение есть только на первом из двух.

Comment: Адреса и маски выставлены верно? Может, подсети разные, и поэтому не получается достучаться, даже если порт открыт?

Comment: Получилось открыть. Вопрос решён.

Answer (score 0):

Видимо одинаковые порты нельзя назначать. При назначении на втором ПК другого номера порта (отличного от первого), соединение появляется.